# I want to run commands after logging into the remote server using shh

Tags: command-line, ssh, mac

```
#! /bin/bash
read -p 'Username: ' user
read -p 'IP: ' ip

ssh "$user"@"$ip"

osascript -e ' tell app "System Events" to display "Hello world"'
```

This file will be ran automatically so it's not like I'm running command after command

It doesn't run the last command and I don't know why

This is terminal on mac

Comment: Pseudo-terminal will not be allocated because stdin is not a terminal.
Password:29:38: syntax error: A “"” can’t go after this identifier. (-2740) thats the error I got

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how ssh exactly operates, but your script is written in a way that it will wait until the ssh command finally terminates. Then will it continue and run your last line (osascript...). To avoid waiting for ssh to return, write a `&` at the end of the ssh line. It will have the interpreter to continue executing the next command in a parallel thread.

Answer (score 1):

Your last command,

```
osascript -e ' tell app "System Events" to display "Hello world"'
```

will be executed only if you exit the remote ssh terminal. In this way you can not achieve what you are trying to do.

Hopefully there is [expect script](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Expect). You can work with the following script,

```bsh
#!/bin/sh
expect <<'END'
set timeout 10
set login "your_username" 
set addr "remote_ip"
set pw "your_password"             # skip this line if you have password less login
spawn ssh $login@$addr
expect "$login@$addr's password:"  # skip this line if you have password less login
send -- "$pw\r"                    # skip this line if you have password less login
expect "~"                         # use your prompt here, I have ~, replace ~ with your prompt
send -- "ls\r"                     # replace ls with your command
expect "~"
send -- "exit\r"
expect eof
END
```

See [How to execute sudo commands with Expect & send commands in bash script?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/307067/how-to-execute-sudo-commands-with-expect-send-commands-in-bash-script)

Comment: If you want to continue with the remote terminal, you can use `interact` command instead of the line `send -- "exit\r"`.